# How to run supervised ML models on a large dataset (15GB) in R?

Tags: r, large-data, feature-selection, sparklyr, supervised-learning

I have a dataset (15 GB): 72 million records and 26 features. I would like to compare 7 supervised ML models (classification problem): SVM, random forest, decision tree, naive bayes, ANN, KNN and XGBoosting. I created a sample set of 7.2 million records (10% of the entire set). Running models on the sample set (even feature selection) is already an issue. It has a very long processing time. I use only RStudio at this moment.

I've been looking for an answer to my questions for days. I tried the following things:
- data.table - still not sufficient to reduce the processing time
- sparklyr - can't copy my dataset, because it's too large

I am looking for a costless solution to my problem. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is the source of the data?  Is it .csv, a database connection, etc?  If we know where the data is coming from we can think about how to get it into Spark.

Comment: Hi Raphael, it's a csv file. No database connection. I just downloaded from a website.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Spark, you can use `sparklyr` to read the CSV file directly.

```r
install.packages('sparklyr')
library(sparklyr)

## You'll have to connect to your Spark cluster, this is just a placeholder example
sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://HOST:PORT")

## Read large CSV into Spark
sdf <- spark_read_csv(sc, 
                      name = "my_spark_table", 
                      path = "/path/to/my_large_file.csv")

## Take a look
head(sdf)
```

You can use `dplyr` functions to manipulate data ([docs](https://spark.rstudio.com/dplyr/)).  To do machine learning, you'll need to use the `sparklyr` functions for SparkML ([docs](https://spark.rstudio.com/mlib/)).  You should be able to find almost all of what you want in `sparklyr`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Colab](http://colab.research.google.com/). This can help you in running your dataset 
 easily.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into the `disk.frame` package.